# What does notation $a|b^\infty$ mean?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, notation

I have definitely crossed it before, but can't find it now.
What does it mean when people write $a \mid b^\infty$?

Comment: There's a notion of "infinitary divisor" which uses a notation somewhat like that, see http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1990-54-189/S0025-5718-1990-0993927-5/S0025-5718-1990-0993927-5.pdf or https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.7597.pdf

Comment: I understand that $a$ has the same prime factors as $b$, with arbitrary multiplicity. F.i., $256|12^\infty$.

Comment: Seems to work! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If we think of $~|~$ as a binary operator returning a Boolean (true or false), we can do the standard trick for interpreting $\infty$:

$$ a | b^{\infty} \;≝\; \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a | b^n $$

From this, we can see that $a|b^\infty$ iff all of $a$'s prime factors divide $b$.

As an example (from Yves's comment above), $256 | 12^\infty$.

Caveat: Notation does not always mean the same thing in different papers. Definitions or contextual information from the relevant source always has priority.